# For bookmarklet in chrome I get the following error: Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome

My issue is with setting up the Bookmarklet in chrome and run the js file from the browser and the following code needed to be add as bookmarkelt in chrome  browser and call a javascript file as mentioned in scriplet text below.
Scriplet text Added in the bookmark named recorder and specified below code in url:

```
javascript: void(require(["http_pathtofile/TpaeInspector.js"],
 function(inspector){new inspector().startup(/*headless*/false,
  "http_pathtofile/TpaeInspector.js")}));
```

To be more specific I have two files:

1. Inspector.js
2. TpaeInspector.js

Both files hosted in my local server:

- http_pathtofile/TpaeInspector.js
- http_pathtofile/Inspector.js

I have slight modification in TpaeInspector.js,  where I have a `define` method in which I have to link Inspector.js file with my http path as             `define(["patht_to_file/Inspector.js"])`.

Any help would be appreciated.